# How do document diff algorithms work?

Tags: algorithm, diff

I want to implement word document differ, what algorithms does it requires to implement?

Comment: Will you be using it to *show* the differences, or *store* the differences in an optimal way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most optimal solution for the LCS problem is [O(ND) Myer's algorithm](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.4.6927), and here is an algorithmic approach which I used to implement to diff office 2007 documents. [Link to algorithm paper](http://www.xmailserver.org/diff2.pdf)

Answer (score 39):

Well, generally speaking, `diff`'ing is usually solved by the [Longest common subsequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).  Also see the "[Algorithm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm) section of the Wikipedia article on [Diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff):

> The operation of diff is based on
>   solving the longest common subsequence
>   problem.
>
> In this problem, you have two
>   sequences of items:
>
> ```
>    a b c d f g h j q z
>
>    a b c d e f g i j k r x y z
> ```
>
> and you want to find the longest
>   sequence of items that is present in
>   both original sequences in the same
>   order. That is, you want to find a new
>   sequence which can be obtained from
>   the first sequence by deleting some
>   items, and from the second sequence by
>   deleting other items. You also want
>   this sequence to be as long as
>   possible. In this case it is
>
> ```
>    a b c d f g j z
> ```
>
> From the longest common subsequence
>   it's only a small step to get
>   diff-like output:
>
> ```
>    e   h i   q   k r x y 
>    +   - +   -   + + + +
> ```

That said, this all works fine with text based documents.  Since Word Documents are effectively in a binary format, and include lots of formatting information and data, this will be far more complex.  Ideally, you could look into automating Word itself as it has the ability to "diff" between documents, as detailed here:

[Microsoft Word Tip: How to compare two documents for differences](http://lifehacker.com/247919/microsoft-word-tip--how-to-compare-two-documents-for-differences)

Comment: There's two purposes to have a diff algorithm implementation: To store only the differences between versions, or to show the differences between versions. These are vastly different (no pun intended). LCS is usually only usable for showing the differences, but for optimal storage, more advanced algorithms are needed. For instance, if you cut a large portion from one section of the document, and paste it into another section, a good storage algorithm would detect that and not store it as "hey, a lot of new data just appeared here".

Comment: @Lasse - Agreed.  Since the original question asker was talking about Word documents, I assumed they would be more interested in the "visual" side of diffing, rather than the storage side.  However, you're correct in that for the storage side, you'd be looking into Delta Encoding/Compression (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding) etc.

Answer (score 15):

A diff is essentially just [a solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Algorithm) to the [longest common sub-sequence problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).

The optimal solution requires knowledge of [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) so it's a fairly complex problem to solve.

However, it can also be done by constructing a suffix-tree. Both algorithms are outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Algorithms).

Comment: That's generally when you assume your document to be a stream of characters or bytes. Here the question is however about word document. Before implementing such an algorithm you need to ask yourself a question is 'Hello World' in blue 8pt Verdana the same as 'Hello World' in red 10pt Arial, etc.

Comment: Yes, obviously the basic algorithms will require additional logic to parse for such differences, but the core of the algorithm will still be the same.

Answer (score 6):

See [An O(ND) Difference Algorithm for C#](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/).

Answer (score 3):

As Ben S indicated, the differencing problem can be addressed generally by solving the longest common sub-sequence problem. More specifically, The [Hunt-McIlroy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt%E2%80%93McIlroy_algorithm) is one of the classic algorithms that have been applied to the problem (e.g in the implementation of Unix' [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) utility).